# Use output of wp_dropdown_categories($args)

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, dropdown

Please be gentle, I'm new to all this coding!
I have finally worked out how to get a frontend dropdown field allowing me to select from EDD categories (I got this from the Codex):

```
<div class="gallery-row">
  <li id="categories">
    <h2><?php _e( 'Categories:' ); ?></h2>
    <form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
      <?php $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'download_category', // EDD custom post type Taxonomy
        'order'    => 'ASC' // Order of the list
      );
      wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
    </form>
  </li>
</div>
```

This is my original code,'selecttaxonomy' is a ACF taxonomy field (and only appears on the  backend):

```
<div class="content clearfix"><div class="gallery-row2">
  <?php
  $current_page = get_query_var('paged'); // Retrieving the data
  $per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
  $offset = $current_page > 0 ? $per_page * ($current_page -1) : 0;
  $taxval = get_field('selecttaxonmy');

  $product_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'download',
    'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
    'offset'            => $offset,
    'download_category' => $taxval,
  );
  $products = new WP_Query($product_args);
  ?>

  <?php if ($products->have_posts()) : $i = 1; ?> //and off into the loop.....
```

What I can't figure out is how to replace 'selecttaxonomy' with the output of the dropdown - help please.
The page I'm working on is: https://ageingdj.com/0anotheredd-test/ (ignore the styling please)

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) will produce a select element with the default name and id of `cat`. You can change these by passing different values for `id` and `cat` in the `$args` array. The default `value` it uses is the term_id. Depending on what you're expected to use in the `get_field()` function, you can also change that in the `$args` array.

```
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'    => 'download_category',
  'order'       => 'ASC',
  'value_field' => 'slug',
);
```

Then in the second part:

```
$cat = esc_attr( $_GET[ 'cat' ] );
$product_args = array(
  'post_type'         => 'download',
  'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
  'offset'            => $offset,
  'download_category' => $cat,
);
```

I've never combined ACF and EDD this way, so it might need some fiddling.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your answer but I'm getting the blank screen from hell!

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter...What do I do on the second part please? Do I delete any rows? and shouldn't 'value_field' => 'slug', and 'download_category' => $cat, return the same value?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I now have results but not what I wat - i'm getting all my posts in reverse (latest first) not the EDD Downloads - wierd.

Comment: Sorry, I just can't get this to work - anyone have any ideas please?  I've also tried get_categories() but had no luck there either.  (all I want is to pass the category selected from the drop down into _$cat_ - thats all).